# Affinity Designer: How to hide parts of objects/curves exceeding canvas - trim view?

Tags: affinity-designer, canvas

I am looking for a "trim view" equivalent in Affinity Designer as the one you find in Adobe Illustrator where the objects selected are trimmed if they exceed the canvas size.

Comment: What makes you think there is a equivalent function?

Comment: The programs are similar (Illustrator and Affinity Designer). However, I can't find that option in the View menu. As I'm new to it, people more experienced with the program might be able to tell me if an equivalent of trim view can be found somewhere. That's why I posted the question.

Comment: The programs are similar because they are constrained by the vector format standards they are geared to produce. Thats right the similarities of the software are mostly because they aim to make PDF, EPS and SVG files. Those constrain the softwares design. There is nothing in the standard about needing to clip artboards. So software vendors are free to innovate here. As there are millions of things that you could have here there is no need to the other software to implement this. But contrast all of the software need to implement clipping mask functionality for example.

Answer (score 1):

I found the way after all this time!

The way of achieving this is going to the main menu View > View Mode > Clip to Canvas. Alternatively, the shortcut is \